# Mapstruct target creation

Tags: java, mapstruct

How does mapstruct decides between the following approaches:

- Get all parameters using getters of source and then call constructor of target to create the mapping.
- Call constructor of target with all null parameters, then set each of them using setters.

  ```
  Target target(Source source) {
    if ( source == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    String a = null;
    String b = null;
    String c = null;

    a = source.getA();
    b = source.getB();
    c = source.getC();

    Target target = new Target( a, b, c );

    return target;
  }
  ```

The second approach could be

```
Target target(Source source) {
    if ( source == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    String a = null;
    String b = null;
    String c = null;

    Target target = new Target( a, b, c );

    target.setA(source.getA());
    target.setA(source.getB());
    target.setA(source.getC());

    return target;
}
```

Here is how the target object class looks like.

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getters
@Setters
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Target {

@NonNull
private String a;

@NonNull
private String b;

@NonNull
private String c;

}
```

Comment: As I see, Mapstruct by default will create target with the default c'tor and then call the setters. If there is no default c'tor, probably will take the c'tor with more arguments, then use setter for any member that is not in a c'tor. Anyway, why you are worried about this ?

Comment: @PeterMmm MapStruct is calling the constructor first with more arguments and then using setters. But problem is the arguments of the target object are non-null and its leading to NullPointerException. Do u know how I can avoid this?

Comment: `But problem is the arguments of the target object are non-null and its leading to NPE`, I don't understand. It sounds to me as a  [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the real problem you have with Mapstruct, get you any exception when you running your code ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I've edited the question as to how the target class looks like. The problem is that Mapstruct generates code using approach 2, and since `@NonNull `annotations are present in target object, its leading to NPE at runtime. Whereas, if Mapstruct would have taken approach 1, then it would have been fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The decision which constructor MapStruct will use is defined in the [Using Constructors](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-constructors) section of the documentation. The rules are the following:

- If a constructor is annotated with an annotation named `@Default` (from any package) it will be used.
- If a single public constructor exists then it will be used to construct the object, and the other non public constructors will be ignored.
- If a parameterless constructor exists then it will be used to construct the object, and the other constructors will be ignored.
- If there are multiple eligible constructors then there will be a compilation error due to ambiguous constructors. In order to break the ambiguity an annotation named `@Default` (from any package) can be used.

From the example you have provided there is a single public constructor (the one from `@AllArgsConstructor`), this means that MapStruct will use the first approach.

```
Target target(Source source) {
  if ( source == null ) {
      return null;
  }

  String a = null;
  String b = null;
  String c = null;

  a = source.getA();
  b = source.getB();
  c = source.getC();

  Target target = new Target( a, b, c );

  return target;
}
```

The second approach from the question is something that doesn't make sense and MapStruct can never generate such a code. If you are seeing something like that then this is a bug.